# Angular js switch between model

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJs and I'm locked on a little part of code:

In my UI, I've a radio button and a table (ng-grid).
In my controller, I've a  json array for each radio choices.

How Can I dynamically bind my table datas dependending on the selected radio button?

Example:
I've a radio with A and B choices.

```
 <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="choice" btn-radio="'A'">A</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="choice" btn-radio="'B'">B</button>
        </div>
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
        </div>
```

Controllers got three arrays:

```
$scope.choice = 'A'
$scope.A = {name: 'A', propA: 'Aprop'}
$scope.B = {name: 'B', propB: 'Bprop'}
$scope.gridOptions = ?????
```

Thank you in advance.

Charlie

Comment: One quick question: what is btn-radio in your radio element? Is it a subsitute for value? edit: I guess it's a bootstrap button radio equivalent.

Comment: Angular-bootstrap (angular-ui) component for radio button. The btnradio directive will switch the $scope.choice value in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch $scope.choice:

```
$scope.$watch('choice', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.gridOptions = $scope.choice;
});
```

This requires that you set $scope.choice to the whole $scope.A object. I don't know if this works with bootstrap radio buttons, but it works with normal angular radio buttons.

Comment: Yes, $watch seems good. I think I'll read the angular documentation next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a scope.$watch expression on "choice" that swaps out the data being assigned to gridOptions.

Inside your controller

```
$scope.$watch('choice', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ($scope.choice == 'A') { 
        $scope.gridOptions = ?????? 
    } else { 
        $scope.gridOptions = ????? 
    }
})
```

**EDIT**: $digest is not necessary, as the watch expression is only called during a digest cycle.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to call $scope.digest(), because $watch triggers a digest cycle anyway.